# Using a Datagrid column value as a parameter Winforms/VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My project has a `DataGridView`, in `frmConsProd`, where the ID column field, receives the prdCod column value from the SQL DB Table.

I need to pass two parameters to second form `frmDetailProd` when I click on the Consult button,`tsbCons`. The first parameter is the string "Consult", however, I'm having trouble sending the ID column value of the `DataGridView` as the second parameter.

Code:

```
Public Class frmConsProd

    Private Sub tsbCons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbConsult.Click
            Try
                Using frm As New frmDetailProd("Consult", "datagrid ID value")
                    frm.txtPrdCod.Enabled = True
                    frm.txtPrdCod.Text = ""
                    frm.ShowDialog()
                End Using

                tsbRefresh.PerformClick()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

How to get the ID value of my `DataGridView`, to be able to send it as a second parameter in the Consult button `tsbCons`?

Comment: Perhaps some reading might help.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0.  Particularly the CurrentRow and SelectedRows properties

Comment: Firstly, is it really a DataGrid or is it actually a DataGridView? Secondly, how was it populated? You probably ought to have bound the data, be it a DataTable or whatever, to a BindingSource and then bound that to the grid. You can then use the Current property of the BindingSource to get the current record.

Comment: It's your prerogative to do so but your naming commenting is terrible. Hungarian Notation is pointless nowadays anyway - it originated when everyone uses basic text editors but now we have a feature-rich IDE - but it was intended for variables. Using it on types is an abuse. What's worse is that you have a prefix to tell you a type is a form and then the name tells you the same thing and nothing more. Are you really that forgetful? You should start using meaningful names at least, and preferably stop using Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @jmcilhinney is a DataGridView.

Comment: @Hursey Ok, I'll look at the link you sent, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only after one value you can try this:

```
dim CellValue = yourGrid.Rows(0).Cells(4).value
```

This example would give you the value of first row, 5th column.

Answer (score 0):

It worked
I created a string and assigned it the value of the datagrid column to be able to pass it as a parameter:
`DIM codPrd As String = DataGridView.CurrentRow,Cells("prdCod").Value`